# Extending a use case

Tags: uml

In a use case diagram, if a use case B extends a use case A, does it mean that an actor who is only associated with use case A ... is also associated with use case B(indirectly)?

I am making a use case diagram for a criminal record management system. The jail superintendent and the police officers both have the privilege to search a criminal via different inputs and then access his entire information. When viewing the information of the criminal, the superintendent also has a choice to modify it while the police officer does not.

Now I have made the use case for "search" and "access info" the same which both the actors can access. The "access info" use case extends the "search" use case. Now, if I extend the "access info" by the "update" use case in the diagram, would it imply that anybody who could access info could also update? That is, will I be wrongly depicting that the police officer could also update the criminal's information.

*I have not made an association between the police officer actor and the update use case. I am confused about the indirect association here...via the search and access information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > if a use case B extends a use case A, does it mean that an actor who is only associated with use case A ... is also associated with use case B

No, it doesn't.  The "extends" relationship can be considered to mean "adds to", in terms of adding additional steps or options to an existing use case.  So if an actor is associated with use case A, they may or may not be associated with the extended use case "B".

You may be looking for inheritance (generalisation) between use cases.  If use case B inherits from use case A then if an actor is associated with use case A, this relationship is inherited by use case B.  The problem with this (although tools let you draw it) is that the semantics of use case inheritance aren't really defined by the standard so you need to define clearly what you mean by it yourself.

Looking at the specifics of your example though, I think you're nearly there.  If you create a use case "Access and Update Info" that extends "Access Info" then only the jail superintendent actor should have access to it.

You could also consider inheritance between actors, which can work quite well.  For example, you could have a base actor "Read Only User" that accesses Search and Access Info.  Then add an actor "Information Owner" (for example) that extends "Read Only User" and adds the reference to the "Access and Update Info" use case.  What you're now doing is describing user interactions in terms of the roles they play in the system rather than in the domain.  That can be useful or can be a barrier to communication - it all rather depends on context.

If communication with end-users is key, I'd suggest keeping the diagram very simple and not using any of these sophisticated relationships.  On the other hand, if those using the model have a fairly good knowledge of UML, using "extends" and actor inheritance can add precision to the model and avoid duplication.